# Compiling Ruby 1.9.1 in MinGW

Tags: ruby, compilation, mingw

I tried following the README file in Ruby 1.9.1 but I can't compile it using MinGW in Windows. Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Details are magical things which allow us to know what the hell you're talking about.  Consider providing some.

Comment: I'm quite confused where to start.

- I installed both MinGW and Cygwin.
- I checked gcc's version in Cygwin (4.4.0)
- I checked gcc's version in MinGW (3.4.5)
- There's no readme in 1.9.1 so I started running Cygwin bash shell.
- I drilled down the location of ruby source folder and typed ./configure.
- After that, I edited the Setup file and uncommented everything.
- I typed "make" and I got this error.
    -> make.exe": Nothing to be done for `all'.

I was building ruby in VC++ 9.0 for a while but I can't get iconv to work.

Comment: Sorry, after few traces, Cygwin has no gcc, it was from my installation of git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling it in windows is TOO complex because you have a lot of dependencies you need to think of (openssl, zlib, readline, etc).

One thing that helped me is by downloading rubyinstaller (http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller). It's not that perfect yet but you can tweak some of the configuration files to work for you (i.e. getting the latest build, modifying the versions, etc).

But then since compiling it is just the beginning of my problems (gems that needs native dependencies like rmagick), I ended up using Ubuntu instead.

Comment: download rubyinstaller then run

  rake ruby18

then run it from sandbox/ruby_mingw/bin

Answer (score 0):

You might want to download and use the GTK "All in one" bundle (http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html). Althought you won't use gtk, it provides builds with development headers/lib for most of the required libraries.

It will also be easier to cross compile it from a linux/unix system.
See this page http://eigenclass.org/hiki/cross+compiling+rcovrt

Last thing, if you want to cross build 1.9.1-p378, this post will be usefull http:// phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/01/install-ruby-191-p378-on-windows-using_22.html